# Rails, how to create, edit, save an attribute that is an combination of related objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Say I have a `Foo` model.  A `Foo` has_many `Bar`. `Bar` stores `value`. A `Foo` stores multiple `Bar` objects as one `combo` object.

For example:

```
f = Foo.find(2)
f.combo
# combo is essentially Bar.find_by(foo: f).pluck(:value).join(" ")
# I want to be able to easily retrieve (like above)
# create/edit/update
f.combo = "moo cow"
# all related existing Bar objects should be updated, 
# and new additions should be created, 
# and no longer relevant ones should be deleted
f.save
# delete
f.combo = nil
# all related Bar objects should be deleted
f.save
```

Is there a rails way of doing the above logic easily?

Comment: do you have a personal policy of not accepting answers?  If so, it's a bad one.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a common approach of updating associated values so afaik there is no standard way to do this. However it is not that difficult to code your way around it depending on what you actually need.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :combo_values, :combo_set

   after_save :update_combo_values

   def combo=(args)
     @combo_values = args
     @combo_set = true
   end

   def update_combo_values
    return unless @combo_set

    self.bars.destroy_all

    if @combo_values
      @combo_values.split(' ').each do |arg|
        bars.create! value: arg 
      end

      @combo_values = nil
      @combo_set = false
    end
  end
end
```